# What is a hypernym for different fields of expertise?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

> It was only after he mastered psychology, philosophy, history, spiritualism, prophesizing and religion, in his old age, that he knew his know he could be at peace. He mastered all these ____ (collective word).

The best fit I can think of *fields* but could mean anything really and is too generic. *Sciences* sounds better since he researched it from a fundamental point of view but history, prophesizing and religion are not *sciences*. It's not in school or academic, and spiritualism is not a subject, so *subjects* doesn't sound correct. Is there a better word for *fields* that sounds more high-brow?

Comment: Would a word such as "disciplins" fit?

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. Yes you can add it as answer

Comment: Yeah,  but please spell it right.

Comment: The hypernyms _disciplines_ and _specialisms_ (the UK variant of specialties) are given; there will almost certainly be no more appropriate answers, though the earlier question _is_ more specific, spiritualism not being taught in many schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correct the spelling of Bitter dregs:

[**disciplines**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/discipline):

> A branch of knowledge, typically one studied in higher education.

Answer (score 3):

How about **specialties?** From Lexido:

> **[specialty](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/specialty)**: A pursuit, area of study, or skill to which someone has devoted much time and effort and in which they are expert.

Your example (edited):

> It was only after he mastered the **specialties** of psychology, philosophy, history, spiritualism, prophesizing, and religion, in his old age, that he knew he could be at peace.

Another possibility that might work in your desired context is **esoterica**. From Lexico:

> **[esoterica](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/esoterica)**: Esoteric or highly specialized subjects or publications.

Your example (edited):

> It was only after he mastered the **esoterica** of psychology, philosophy, history, spiritualism, prophesizing, and religion, in his old age, that he knew he could be at peace.